# Firebase Crashlytics not reporting crashes after Fabric Migration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

Recently we migrated our app from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics and Firebase Analytics. In android, everything works like a charm after following Google documentation. The problem is that in iOS we get no report on Firebase Crashlytics (works perfectly on Firebase Analytics)after following the same documentation.

**Paths:**

Dev Google Service Info Plist:
`Supporting Files > Firebase > Dev > GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist`

Prod Google Service Info Plist:
`Supporting Files > Firebase > Prod > GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist`

Empty Plist:
`Supporting Files > GoogleService-Info.plist`

**Build Phases:**

Run Script *(GoogleService-Info.plist assignment)*:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM="${PROJECT_DIR}/Supporting Files/Firebase/Prod/GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist"
else
    GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM="${PROJECT_DIR}/Supporting Files/Firebase/Dev/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist"
fi

GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO="${PROJECT_DIR}/Supporting Files/GoogleService-Info.plist" 
cp "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM}" "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO}"
```

Run Script *(Firebase Crashlytics Run)*:

```
# Run Firebase Crashlytics

"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/Supporting\ Files/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

**AppDelegate:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
   // Set Google -Info.plist for enviroment
       let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: ULima.getInfoPlist(buildType: ULima.buildType), ofType: "plist")
   if let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!) {
       // Use Firebase library to configure APIs and Crashlytics
       FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
   }
  [...]
}
```

**Crashlytics Console:**

[image: Crashlytics Console]

**What I already tried:**

- Checking if bundle id from project and Firebase console match
- Checking if bundle id has and empty space
- Running Project, press Stop, open app in simulator (so debugger doesn't interfere with crashlytics) and force crash
- Waited more than 2 days for the crashes to appear
- Setting Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File.
- Running just `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`
- Check with `Crashlytics.crashlytics().didCrashDuringPreviousExecution()`
- Added this to `AppDelegate`:

```
        Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)

        Crashlytics.crashlytics().checkForUnsentReports { _ in
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().sendUnsentReports()
        }
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Usually for iOS you would need to build/run the app and then stop Xcode. Then open the app directly in the device and crash it and then re-run it. The debugger from Xcode prevents Crashlytics from collecting crash data.

Comment: I already did that, check in what I tried :D

Comment: lol didn't see that part. The other thing I can think of is the Crashlytics version being used. In the Podfile.lock file, what is the Crashlytics version? If possible, add this flag to the scenma: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable_debug_logging do the same steps I mentioned above but re-run the ap from Xcode so you can see the debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

The run script doesn't look fine to me. There should be one or two separated commands:

1. run (start) Firebase Crashlytics:
   `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"` (see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#swift))
2. if Firebase Crashlytics is unable to process the dSYM files itself, you should upload the dSYM file to Firebase to get deobfuscated crash reports (see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-fabric-sdk))

So I suggest you to edit your Firebase Crashlytics *Run Script* just to Run Crashlytics (without uploading any dSYM file). If it helps and you can see a crash in console, than you can check if dSYM file is missing (so another script for uploading dSYM will be needed).

Comment: Hi, I already tried without the -gsp command, and set Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File. I get nothing about Crashlytics in console, no errors, no logs, nothing.